# How to know which URL an Android application tries to visit?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This is a black box test, which means I　don't have any way to access the source code. Because I have to reproduce the error, file a report, and then present to the programmer (who are not our company's employee), I have to find the crashing URL / http / xhttp request.

Is there any way to do so on the SDK emulator?

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using a [network sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer)?